# Jenkins active choice parameter not understand the "@" symbol" and encodes it. How can one decode it while passing it as parameter in build command?

Tags: maven, jenkins, cucumber, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

[Groovy script to pass parameter tag value dynamically on the basis of project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mjWD8.png)

[Once configured, the @ in the value is encoded, I want to avoid that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J48Ko.png)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that while passing the values between parameters Active Choice converts it with HTML Encoding , you can see all the values which will be changed using /script endpoint of jenkins with below code : -

```js
import static org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml
'!@£$%^&*()_+€-={}[]:"|;\'\\<>?,./~'.each {
    println "$it -> ${escapeHtml( it )}"
}
```

```html
! -> !
@ -> @
£ -> &pound;
$ -> $
% -> %
^ -> ^
& -> &amp;
* -> *
( -> (
) -> )
_ -> _
+ -> +
€ -> &euro;
- -> -
= -> =
{ -> {
} -> }
[ -> [
] -> ]
: -> :
" -> &quot;
| -> |
; -> ;
' -> '
\ -> \
< -> &lt;
> -> &gt;
? -> ?
, -> ,
. -> .
/ -> /
~ -> ~
```

I resolved this using org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml class.

You can convert the received parameter using below code snippet : -

```js
import static org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml
String unEscapedString = "a &amp; b"
String escapedHTML = unescapeHtml(unEscapedString)
print(escapedHTML)
```

This will print a & b which was expected by code.